# Remove all instance of "page + some_number" from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have strings which include page numbers in the format "Page 2". I'd like to remove these page numbers.

**A string might be:**

"The first is Page 10 and then Page 1 and then Page 12"

**Current implementation:**

Is there a more elegant way to remove all "Page #{some_number}" than below?

```
page_numbers = [
    'Page 1', 
    'Page 2', 
    'Page 3', 
    'Page 4', 
    'Page 5', 
    'Page 6', 
    'Page 7', 
    'Page 8', 
    'Page 9',
    'Page 10',
    'Page 11',
    'Page 12']

x = "The first is Page 10 and then Page 1 and then Page 12"

for v in page_numbers:
    x = x.replace(v, ' ')

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer with `re.sub` is on the right track, but incomplete. If you only want to remove *certain* page numbers, then a simple `re.sub` solution on it's own will not be enough. You'll need to supply a callback to get this working.

```
p_set = set(page_numbers)

def replace(m):
    p = m.group()
    return ' ' if p in p_set else p
```

Now, pass `replace` as a callback to `re.sub` -

```
>>> re.sub('Page \d+', replace, x)
'The first is   and then   and then  '
```

The second argument to `re.sub` accepts a *callback*, which is invoked when a match is found. The corresponding `match` object is passed as an argument to `replace`, which should return a *replacement value*.

I've also converted `page_numbers` to a `set`. This lets me perform constant time lookups on `p_set` when determining whether a matched string is to be kept or discarded.

---

For more flexibility, you can support removal of page numbers within a range -

```
def replace(m):
    return ' ' if int(m.group(1)) in range(1, 13) else m.group()
```

And call it appropriately -

```
>>> re.sub('Page (\d+)', replace, x)
'The first is   and then   and then  '
```

Which is more effective than maintaining a list/set of page numbers, assuming your range for removal is continuous. Another thing to note is that membership checks with a `range` object using the `in` operator are computationally cheap (constant time).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "The first is Page 10 and then Page 1 and then Page 12"
>>> re.sub(r'(\s?Page \d{1,3})', ' ', x)
'The first is  and then  and then '
```

`re.sub` will replace all matches of the regular expression with the second parameter (the replacement string) on x (the third parameter)

So, what is that regular expression doing?

- `\s?` just eats a space before the *Page n* text, if it's there
- `Page` matches exactly the `"Page "` string (with a space)
- `\d{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 digits. If you're ok with handling only to 99, use `\d{1,2}`. If you need more, just adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex like so:

```
import re

x ="The first is Page 10 and then Page 1 and then Page 12"
print(re.sub(r'Page \d+', '', x))
```

This finds all "Page" followed by space and any number of digits and replaces it with nothing.

If you want to keep spacing even between the words do this:

```
re.sub(r'Page\s\d+\s', '', x)
```

This will match the space after and replace it as well since if it doesnt you will have 2 spaces (one from before Page and one from after it)